# How to organize submarine fleet?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I created a lot of submarines as Germany to try to bring british industry to a halt by cutting off the supply. How to organize submarine fleets for best interception percentage? What are the tradeoffs?

Group size?
For subby hit-and-run smaller fleets (1-3) sounds better but one can hardly afford a leader to all of them, let alone one with a spotter or sub-master skill. Also, I imagine too large a fleet would not be optimal either.

Distribution?
When to use any such "properly sized" fleets in 1 specific region vs have larger overlapping areas for each sub fleet?

Unfortunately the game seems to lack any strategic "spreadsheet" or diagrams to measure trade interdiction progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Broscience" says the groups of 7-9 subs are most optimal for Germany - good punch and still good stealth.

I am not aware of the possibility to change a supply root tranjectory so it only make sense to set the sub at the busiest regions. If you can handle it one sub group only one region.

Recommended regions: Coast of Africa and mid Atlantic - less British fleet and a lot of traffic, avoid English channel, as too heavily guarded.

General sub tips so far:
- I call sub fleets "sub 1", "sub 2", etc
- Create a many production queues as i have sub fleets and direct the newly produced subs to the fleet directly
- Set engagement level to "not engage" and repair priority to yellow
- Avoid placing subs to the ports easily accessible by enemy bombers (unless you have air superiority) - so basically avoid English channel coast line
- Place a good commander
- Combine subs with nav bombers

Yes, the ledgers are gone, they might be back though. If you keep sub notifications for a month you can see on the map which regions are the most successful and therefore find a good engagement region.

Comment: > I am not aware of the possibility to change a supply route trajectory

One can mark naval regions to be avoided if possible, however, I don't know if AI uses this mechanic or not.

Comment: Yes it does, it also deploys aws. But in 4 years a lot of changed and meta is changing all the time. Also in single game it does not really matter.